# Oracle With, Case When statement missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, with-statement, case-when

Hi I am trying to create a view in Oracle SQL Developer. 
I would like the view to be everything from raw_test with a new column As 'Exclusion Reason' where the exclusion reason value is 'Patient_ID_Missing' and 'Duplicate_MRN respectively.

```
With
Dup_MRN AS
  (SELECT *
FROM raw_test
   WHERE mrn IN (  SELECT mrn
                 FROM raw_test
             GROUP BY mrn
               HAVING COUNT (*) > 1))
Select raw_test.*,
    case when raw_test.patient_ID_CDW is null then 'Patient_ID_Missing'
    case when Dup_MRN.mrn is not null then 'Duplicate_MRN'
  End as "Exclusion_reason"
From raw_test              
Left join dup_mrn.mrn on raw_test.mrn = dup_mrn.mrn
```

When I run this I get the error "missing keyword" but I can't figure out what exactly I'm missing.

Thank you in advance for you help

*Brilliant! thank you all for the help, I definitely missed the second case clause in there. I thought it was something simple, you can look at a field of clover for hours before you see one with four leaves : )

Comment: you have an extra `case`, it's `case when "something" then "something" when ...`

Comment: If one of the below answers solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: This message would have been clearer if it said "EXTRA KEYWORD" and not "MISSING KEYWORD".  I guess they wanted you to put in the `END` before the 2nd (but not needed here) CASE.

Answer (score 1):

You are using CASE statement incorrectly.

```
SELECT raw_test.*,
    CASE
    WHEN raw_test.patient_ID_CDW IS NULL THEN 'Patient_ID_Missing'
    WHEN Dup_MRN.mrn IS NOT NULL THEN 'Duplicate_MRN'
    ELSE ''
    END AS "Exclusion_reason"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [`case` statement](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php) incorrectly. It should have the format of

```
case
  when exp1 then thing1
  when exp2 then thing2
  else default_thing
end as field_name
```

---

```
with up_mrn as (
  select 
    *
  from 
    raw_test
  where 
    mrn in (
      select 
        mrn
      from 
        raw_test
      group by 
        mrn
        having count (*) > 1
    )
)
select 
  raw_test.*
  , case 
    when raw_test.patient_id_cdw is null 
      then 'Patient_ID_Missing'
    when dup_mrn.mrn is not null 
      then 'Duplicate_MRN'
    else null
  end as "Exclusion_reason"
from 
  raw_test              
  left join dup_mrn.mrn 
    on raw_test.mrn = dup_mrn.mrn
```